# Unable to use price:plus_tax with Matrix field

Tags: cartthrob

I've got a matrix for my price modifiers. I don't map the base price field because I want to use the modifiers price as the full price.

So when I use my {price} variable I get the price without tax. I've tried {price:plus_tax}, but that doesn't seem to work. 
Everything is ok when I view my cart, but I really want the option to show the price with or without the tax in the step before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price:plus_tax tag won't work with a text field. It needs to be one of the various CartThrob Price Fieldtypes to use that tag.

If you use the `{exp:cartthrob:item_options}` tag to display your matrix modifiers, you'll be able to use :plus_tax.

Comment: That does work indeed! But I did a little custom coding for my purpose and did it this way.
`
{if member_group != "7"}
        {exp:cartthrob:arithmetic prefix="" expression="({price} * {cart_tax_rate}) + {price}"}
{/if}